# I have a long list with sub-items which fall into the same category , wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have a long list with subitems which fall into the same category. As the submenu is growing, I want the submenu to break over in listing the sub menu items in 3 columns. Anybody out there knowing the trick how to do that?

see here illustrated my issue:

```
topmenu item
-submenu 1
-submenu 2
-submenu 3
-submenu 4
-submenu 5
-submenu 6
-submenu 7
-submenu 8
-submenu 9
-submenu 10
-submenu 11
-submenu 12
-submenu 13
-submenu 14
-submenu 15
-submenu 16
-submenu 17
-submenu 18
-submenu 19
-submenu 20
```

I need it to be like this:

```
topmenu item
-submenu 1   -submenu 6   -submenu 11
-submenu 2   -submenu 7   -submenu 12
-submenu 3   -submenu 8   -submenu 13
-submenu 4   -submenu 9   -submenu 14
-submenu 5   -submenu 10  -submenu 15
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear to me.

Comment: welcome to SO, we are going to need some code sample or even better a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ )in order to reply corectly to your question

Comment: can you share the fiddle for previous structure? It will be helpful to provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flexbox to do this

**[5 items demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yQ5AR/10/)** | **[10 items demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yQ5AR/8/)** |  **[15 items demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yQ5AR/9/)**

### MArkup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
    <div class="item">14</div>
    <div class="item">15</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container{
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.item{
      height: 20px;
      background: maroon;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 columns module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
</div>

.container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuKjS/